# How Kriging, Bochner theorem and Positive definite (PD) function are related?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, statistics, soft-question, definition

This question referes to the link:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kriging

I can understand the relation between Bochner's theorem and PD function. But could not properly understand and connect all three elements namely, Kriging, Bochner's theorem and PD function. I would love to know a clear connection between these three. May be these three are related through Fourier transform, my wild guess; any clarification would be appreciated.

Comment: I added a tag. There may be a better one, but you need something to do with Statistics I think. Wish I had time to look into this more. Very interesting topic and a good question.

Comment: @TrialAndError Thank you.

Comment: @Creator, did you ever solve this?  I'd like to know the answer....thanks.

Comment: @Hunle I concluded that Kriging estimation works because of Bochner's theorem which is applicable to PD function.

Comment: I've heard that as well....but specifically, how?  Can you answer your own question thoroughly and accept your answer?

Comment: @Hunle, I will try to do it and let you know. Thank you for your interest.

Comment: @Hunle Now I feel my question is not proper. There is no relation between the theorem and Kriging. Kriging is an interpolation  method and other terms (PD function and Bochner theorem) are not related.